# How is API Explorer linked to QB Files?

Tags: api, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I created a test QBO company and an IPP App. I can run the the API Explorer OK. It's great.

When I go through the API explorer screens it gives me the opportunity to connect to the QBO file that I created. How does it know to just show me my QBO file? Is it because I use the same name and password (I think) for both my QBO company and the API explorer?

Answer (score 1):

If you're already logged in to any *.Intuit.com domain, then it shows you the QuickBooks company files that are linked to your Intuit username. This is what you're seeing - you're logged in to manage your IPP app already, so you're also logged in automatically to other Intuit services.

Otherwise, it prompts you to log in to your Intuit account.